# Зачем для Q-learning нужна память?

Tags: нейронные-сети, машинное-обучение

Вопрос такой, зачем для Q-learning нужна память, если для предсказания действия (`Q[s',a']`), можно использовать НС, которая грубо говоря и так сама в себе хранит предыдущий опыт?

[image]

[https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-обучение](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)